# divide image into nine parts and want to work in the central part of the image using python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to fragment image in to nine parts and wants to work in the center part of the image.

```
import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2
# define the upper and lower boundaries of the HSV pixel
# intensities to be considered 'skin'
lower = np.array([0, 48, 80], dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array([20, 255, 255], dtype="uint8")
frame=cv2.imread("image/girl.jpg")
frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)
converted = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
skinMask = cv2.inRange(converted, lower, upper)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11, 11))
skinMask = cv2.erode(skinMask, kernel, iterations=2)
skinMask = cv2.dilate(skinMask, kernel, iterations=2)

skinMask = cv2.GaussianBlur(skinMask, (3, 3), 0)
skin = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=skinMask)

cv2.imshow("images", skin)
```

Skin is the image and i want to fragment in to 9 parts and want to access central part thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code does not show a single line about dividing the image into 9 parts. What have you done so far ?

Comment: i am going to check if the pixel are skin pixels or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use Numpy slicing:

```
rows, cols = skin.shape
centralImg = skin[int(rows/3):int(2*rows/3), int(cols/3):int(2*cols/3)]
```